# Shadow/gradient in top and bottom of element

Tags: html, css, datepicker

I was looking for a multi component date picker like the one in the image under, but didn't find anything on Github, or elsewhere.

So I decided to make one. I'm having problems implementing the CSS where it fades out on top and bottom.

I thought about using `:before` and `:after` in the container, but no success. Can I apply gradients in `:before` and `:after`

[image]

For example:

```css
ol {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 8em;
    height: 6em;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.5em solid black;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 0px;
}

li {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    line-height: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccf;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li>2010</li>
    <li>2011</li>
    <li>2012</li>
    <li>2013</li>
    <li>2014</li>
    <li>2015</li>
    <li>2016</li>
    <li>2017</li>
    <li>2018</li>
    <li>2019</li>
    <li>2020</li>
</ol>
```

How to make the shadow on top and bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div class="date-picker">
   <ol>
      <li>2010</li>
      ...
   </ol>
   <div class="shadow"></div>
</div>
```

With the `date-picker` styled however you like (setting width and height), and the following CSS:

```
.date-picker {                                                                  
    position: relative;                                                         
    width: 8em;                                                                 
    height: 6em;                                                                
    border: 0.5em solid black;                                                  
    border-radius: 0.5em;                                                       
}

ol {                                                                            
    position: absolute;                                                         
    overflow: hidden;                                                           
    width: 100%;                                                                
    height: 100%;                                                               
    text-align: center;                                                         
    margin: 0;                                                                  
    padding: 0;                                                                 
}                                                                               

li {                                                                            
    margin: 0px;                                                                
    list-style: none;                                                           
    padding: 0.5em 0;                                                           
    line-height: 1em;                                                           
    border: 1px solid #ccf;                                                     
}                                                                               

.shadow {                                                                       
    position: absolute;                                                         
    width: 100%;       
    height: 100%;                                                               
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), transparent, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));                                                             
}
```

This creates a gradient image overlay positioned in front of the `ol` which is the image's sibling. Keep in mind that the z-index of `.shadow` needs to be larger than that of the `ol`.

EDIT: Looking more closely at the image you posted, the gradient seems closer to quadratic than linear. If you want the list to look more rounded, making a non-linear gradient in photoshop or something would make it look much more three dimensional.

Comment: I don't see how your CSS makes a difference... https://jsfiddle.net/5v40a4bf/ (I'm using Chrome and I see no change)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't test it. I'm updating with something that should work. It should be `position: absolute`, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply gradients in `:before` and `:after` elements.

Example:

```
ol {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 8em;
    height: 6em;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    border: 0.5em solid black;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 0px;
}

ol:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom : 80%;
    content: "";
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0) 100%);
    z-index: -1;
    pointer-events: none;
}

ol:after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 20%;
    bottom : 0;
    content: "";
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0.1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0) 100%);
    z-index: -1;
    pointer-events: none;
}

li {
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0.5em 0;
    line-height: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccf;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any difference in the jsFiddle with your CSS.. https://jsfiddle.net/5v40a4bf/1/

Comment: Sorry, I wrote incorrect rgba colors.
[correct example](https://jsfiddle.net/5v40a4bf/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it by using gradients not on `:before` / `:after` but in a new div which floats with `position: absolute;` like:

```
.fader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 9em;
    background: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="date-picker">
    <ol>
        <li>2010</li>
        <li>2011</li>
        ...
    </ol>
    <div class="fader"></div>
</div>
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bo7dyx83/

Comment: This is basically what my answer was. You should accept your own answer if you're still convinced neither of the other two work.

Comment: The point of my answer was not to provide you with CSS, but to tell you how to approach your original problem (not to mention that the code on the link you provided works on my browser). You don't have to accept my answer, but you should close the question if you have a working solution.